# Unable to deploy a node.js project on Azure, Bcrypt is the culprit

Tags: node.js, azure, bcrypt

I am currently working on a node.js project which is deployed on Azure. I just added password encryption using bcrypt. Everything is fine on my test computer but when I deploy on Azure, the deployment failed and I've got this message :

```
node-gyp rebuild
C:\DWASFiles\Sites\invata\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\node_modules\bcrypt>node  "D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-   gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild 
gypnpm ERR! bcrypt@0.7.6 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! `cmd "/c" "node-gyp rebuild"` failed with 1
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@0.7.6 install script.
```

BCrypt installation is a bit tricky as it required to download and install openSSL. So is there a possibility to deploy such module on azure or is it hopeless ?

Thanks,
Stéphane

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After some investigation, I come across another bcrypt module, this one is a native JS module and it works flawlessly on Azure : https://github.com/shaneGirish/bcrypt-nodejs

Comment: +1 because i had exact the problem. you should mark this as the answer!

Comment: bcrypt was also throwing an error for me on Azure. Swapping it with crypt-nodejs did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: Nice - a straight swap for me

Comment: This is a solution, but since bcrypt is specifically designed to be slow, this could be an issue in a high volume server. The advantage of native bcrypt module is the bcrypt calculations themselves are run asynchronously. Even though bcrypt-nodejs implies it supports async by providing `compare` and `compareSync`, both are actually synchronous operations, just the "async" one happens on next tick. It still halts all operations until the bcrypt calculations are done and is not truly asynchronous.

Comment: Has anyone come up with a better solution to this issue? I switched to a native JS implementation of bcrypt as suggested, but it's on an order of 3x slower than the native version. I can see this adding up and causing problems in a high-volume environment.

Comment: In my case i had to uninstall bcrypt, then install bcrypt-nodejs and finally install again bcrypt

Answer (score -1):

I just encountered this problem myself.

After searching for a solution for the past hour, the following worked flawlessly for me:

1. Goto your Web App console (found in the web app **Tools**)
2. type: `npm install bcrypt`

i received no output following the command, but going into the Web App node_modules folder i found bcrypt and all its dependencies there.

continuous deployment worked flawlessly ever since, hope this helps others!

Comment: Sometimes when doing `npm install` npm fails to build some libraries, you can try `npm rebuild` to make npm rebuild all the libraries that require building.

Comment: Not a good practice running npm install commands on the Azure Web App, the deploy should be fully automatic, install the bcrypt-nodejs seems like the best solution.